# Charging phone battery with a lower voltage, coming from a bike charger?

Tags: usb, charger, usb-device

Since travel by bike a lot, and use my phone very often during those trips, I tried designing a USB phone bikecharger that would use my bike-dynamo that also powers my lamp.

Yesterday, I did my first tests. Without load, the circuit would give me 9,3V (even when the wheel was not spinning, which was a surprise to me :) ). With a 47 Ohm load, it would still give 9.3V. This is way too much for USB ofcourse, but 47Ohm is still quite big I think.

When a 10Ohm load was applied (I assumed 5V USB-voltage, 500mA charge current --> 10 ohm), the voltage dropped to 3,5V (it kept quite stable, it didn't fluctuate all that much. It seems the wheel speed doesn't influence the output voltage, except for when it spins too slow and the voltage is cut off entirely. I assume this is some kind of protection mechanism in the dynamo?).

So here's my question: what would happen is I were to attach a phone to this charger?

My guess is that 3.5V is not enough to overcome the <s>internal resistance of the phone battery</s>  threshold for the charge circuitry of the phone, so it will be blocked a few ms, but because of the open circuit, the voltage will rise to 5V and that will eventually be enough to charge. So in practice, it will just charge with a lower current (same as charging your phone on the USB-port of a netbook. Those often can't provide enough current, and the phone just charges slowly).

Is my guess right?

What are the risks of charging a phone-battery with too little voltage?

Should I worry about the charger outputting 9V when the phone battery is full? Because there won't be any load anymore then.

Thanks in advance!

ps. I also checked the signal with an oscilloscope to check the purity of the DC, and it was pretty clean. There were no big spikes and the level was quite stable. (I didn't try to pitch pennies on noise-supressing capacitors ;) )

Edit: added my schematic

[image: Schematic]

EDIT2: J3 in the schematic is an <s>LM2596 Buck module, using a</s> MP1584 step-down regulator module.

EDIT3: I was doing some tests a few minutes ago, and I guess I had misconfigured the LM2596 (doh...). I think the 9.3V issue is not existent anymore (I've only tested it on a bench power supply right now, but I assume it'll be the same when I test it on my bike again). 
So now the only question that remains: Is there any risk to applying a voltage too low to the phone? And will my above assumption hold true?

EDIT4: Currently testing it with some old phones, with my bike on a treadmill. 5V is constantly stable now for every speed above 6km/h, and charge current is 300mA, also pretty stable (100mA on an older phone). The phones themselves also indicate that they're being charged 
At first glance, everything seems to be working, but... the charge percentage is barely going up. I'm not sure yet if this is because the batteries are very old and haven't been used in ages, or if there's still something wrong with the circuit. More testing will be needed ;)

EDIT5: as pointed out by @Ale...chenski the path between the rectifier bridge and the two elco's is wrong and will be removed.

Comment: *My guess is that 3.5V is not enough to overcome the internal resistance of the phone battery* Why do you write this? How is the battery's internal resistance relevant? (Hint: it is not) You really need to learn how a battery in a phone is charged. Your contraption only needs to supply **5 V** while being able to deliver enough current (like 1 A), then the charging circuit **which is inside the phone** will charge the battery. If your circuit cannot supply enough current then chances are that the phone will not charge the battery at all.

Comment: Bimpelrekkie: "internal resistance" is a wrong wording indeed, I meant that the phone will not charge because the voltage is too low --> the voltage will build up because of the open circuit --> 5V is eventually reached --> the battery will charge. This is what I meant.

Comment: What does "LM2596 Buck module, using a MP1584 step-down regulator." mean? Is it a LM2596 or is it a MP1584? These are different chips.

Comment: Are you familiar with [the "forums lader"](http://www.forumslader.de/news/newsdetails/?tx_ttnews%5BbackPid%5D=178&tx_ttnews%5Btt_news%5D=93&cHash=3b65fa3a89e225424da2f6739dc25623)?

Comment: @RalfStubner: No, I wasn't aware of that one. It looks very neat and compact though. Maybe I should have used that design :)

Comment: @tangrs: You are right. I made a mistake there. Apparently the vendor named this module to the wrong chip... Hence I thought it was the module name, but apparently it's an entire different chip that is not used on this board. Confusing...

Comment: Normal hub dynamos are nominally 6V and 3W. There are commercial products which just work, in case you weren't aware.

Comment: Modern phone may allow fast charging with 9V or 12V, so maybe 9V can also be safe.

Check your phone's power adapter: does it list only 5V or something like 5V-12V as output voltage?

Comment: @Vi0: USB should always be 5V, no matter how modern the phone is. What you are probably referring to is Dash charge, or something similar, where there is circuitry installed that allows for temporary higher charging currents at certain times in the charge process. Even though my cellphone is equipped with Dash Charge, this bike-charger will not support it.

Comment: To start, as shown, your rectifier bridge is wired completely wrong: C1-C2 joint shouldn't be connected to AC input.

Comment: Also, what is your "bike dynamo"? Is one terminal grounded to body, or the voltage is floating? is it AC or already DC?

Comment: ElectroBoom [tried something like this and destroyed his phone](https://youtu.be/wdgiTQffiwk?t=144). Don't be ElectroBoom.

Comment: @Ale..chenski: It is incredible how I missed that! I only did some minor changes on a design I found on the internet. This error was also in the original schematic! I can't imagine how many people also used this flawed design, just like I did, without noticing. (Nobody mentioned it in the comments. Maybe I should?)

Comment: @Ale..chenski: I'm fairly sure it's floating AC.

Comment: @immibis: Isn't ElectroBoom some kind of parody channel where the guy deliberately does incredibly stupid things to create sparks or flames? 
How is his video related to what I did? He used a crank-generator straight hooked up to his phone. My question above clearly shows that this is not what I am attempting... Also: I test with Multimeter and oscilloscope first, and afterwards with old unused phones. I'm not risking my new phone before I know everything works flawlessly.

Comment: @Opifex Yes, ElectroBoom does stupid things on purpose - in reality he knows what he's doing. I hope for that experiment he was using a brand new burner (heh) phone. However, I don't think the experiments are fake. The point is that the crank generator made a voltage that's too high when it's unloaded, and that destroyed the phone. I would expect that to happen with your bike generator too, because it *also* produces too high a voltage when it's unloaded.

Comment: If your generator needed a 10k ohm load in order for the voltage to go down that would be one thing. You could just add a 10k ohm load permanently. But a minimum load of 30-ish ohms is too low to be comfortable with.

Comment: @immibis: it said 10 Ohm, not 10k Ohm. 10 Ohm is 500 mA, that's a huge current to only have to keep the voltage in check. Also: I think keeping the voltage in check by adding a load isn't really a good solution, and very unreliable.

Comment: @Opifex Yes, that's why I said 10k would've been okay, but 30 isn't. (and by extension 10 isn't either)

Answer (score 8):

First of all, the USB is not being fed directly to the phone’s battery. It’s actually being fed to the battery charger circuitry inside the phone. You cannot safely directly connect a normal regulated voltage source to a lithium ion battery without the distinct possibility of an explosion and/or fire! The charger circuitry adjusts the voltage and current fed to the battery depending on the state of charge.

Then, your question becomes what happens when you feed incorrect voltage into a phone’s charger circuitry. This would depend on the specific model, but we can generalize. With too low voltage, such as 3.5 volts, the phone will probably ignore it and refuse to charge. With too high voltage, such as 9.3 volts, the phone is likely to either shut down to protect itself or be damaged by the excessive voltage.

Your circuitry, which you have not really described, is totally unsuited to charging a mobile phone! You have a good chance of seriously damaging its circuitry. You should probably find a commercially produced buck/boost module, capable of taking in the maximum voltage from your dynamo and outputting a stable 5 volts at 500 ma, or whatever your phone needs.

Comment: You're right, I didn't describe the circuitry. I added my schematic to the original post now. 
A colleague of mine suggested a buck/boost module while I was designing it, but I assumed the boost wasn't necesarry because I would be able to achieve a stable 5V out of the dynamo. A buck/boost would have made the whole pcb a lot more bulky than I deemed acceptable on a bike.

Comment: I am aware the USB is not fed directly into the battery. The voltage would be a multiple of 3.7V, so the 5V from the USB will be lowered internally. 
What I meant was, that the internal circuitry of the phone would cut everything down while it's lower than 5V, which would cause the voltage to rise because of the open contact. Once it reaches 5V, the circuit would close again. This is what I meant (but I admit it was very badly worded).

Thing is that the 9.3V is only when it has no load, or a very high load. Wouldn't a normal USB charger also have a high voltage when it doesn't have a load?

Comment: @Opifex, no a normal USB charger will always output 5V regardless of load (assuming not USB-C).

Comment: @tangrs: this is not a normal USB-charger. The voltage will dip significantly if the load is too heavy.

Comment: @Opifex in that case, your design needs to switch off the output completely if the input voltage dips too low. USB needs 5V (+/-5%). Anything else is out of spec.

Comment: @tangrs: you're right. A good design would implement a voltage cut-off. I didn't implement this in my design, and was wondering what the effects would be of the situation described above.

Comment: @Opifex, "A colleague of mine suggested a buck/boost module" - and he might be totally right. The problem is that the voltage from generator will be variable and depending on traffic, and not all buck converters like intermediate voltages.

Comment: @Ale..chenski: It seems like this is not the case for my bike-generator in particular. It cuts off voltage when the wheel is spinning too slow (<6km/h +-), and outputs a fixed voltage above that. There is not linear correlation between speed and output voltage.

Comment: @Opifex, what is the cut-off voltage? My point is that if the voltage is between 3 and 8 V, the behavior of MP1584 is not defined and can be anything. Buck-boost/SEPIC converters don't have this problem.

Comment: @Ale..chenski: I can't remember, but can check again and let you know if you want. 
However, I did test the output voltage of the circuit with spinning, non-spinning and slow-spinning wheel, and the only voltages I got as an output were 0V  and 5V. So as far as I can tell, the circuit did seem to work.

Comment: @Opifex,  "the only voltages I got as an output were 0V and 5V" - good for you, I just wanted to warn you, so you won't fry your phone...

Comment: @Ale..chenski: Yes, thanks a lot for that! I appreciate the criticism! :) 
In any case, I test in multiple phases: Multimeter --> oscilloscope --> old unused phone --> new phone. Just to make sure I don't blow up anything expensive ;)

Answer (score 5):

Obviously you have not any data of how your phone's USB connection is specified except it's USB. Don't risk your phone, the voltage must be 5V if you haven't better data. Too low voltage doesn't harm - except there's no charging, but 9V probably does.

If you can get over 5V with the max current that your phone eats from exact 5V, then have a voltage regulator which drops the extras off, even 7805 with a couple of capacitors can be ok altough it wastes nearly half of the energy. A switching converter would be better in that sense.

If it happens that you do not get enough voltage ie. when biking at a reasonable speed your dynamo doesn't give 5V or more with the needed load, you can possibly help it by having a boost capable regulator, but I guess it doesn't help, because the current under 5V jumps up If you must produce at 5V a certain current.

My phone has a special ability: It sees if the USB connector hasn't the wanted output capablity and warns me: Use a proper USB charger for faster charging. It still seems to charge. You possibly have the same in your phone. You can test it by adding a series resistor. If your phone can reduce automatically the charging current, it can solve the problem caused by an underpowered dynamo.

One thing to consider: Carry an external high capacity USB battery pack. It can be quite big if you have a bike. If you can charge it with mains voltage now and then, you do not need a dynamo based charger.

Comment: 7805 would be too bulky because it requires a heatsink, and also wastes a lot of the energy. I used an MP1584 step-down regulator instead.

Comment: @Opifex MP1584 is fine. A roadworthy construction is your next challenge.

Comment: What do you mean with "construction"? A box? Or the circuit?
was planning on 3D-printing something easily attachable to the frame.

Comment: A whole charger (=circuit, cables, connectors, box, fastening) which doesn't disintegrate under vibrations, don't get too hot nor melt in direct sunlight and keeps the water out. This is NOT trivial if it's a part of your bike. It's easier if you carry it.

Comment: Yes, ofcourse. You are right. This is still a prototype for now, so everything will be pretty basic for testing. But once everything is proven to work, and safe for the phones (I will test on old phones first), I will make work of a decent construction.

Comment: @Opifex Your comments and additions to the question show that you know something and do not rely on pure luck. I rewrote my answer .

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/90201/discussion-between-opifex-and-user287001).

Answer (score 0):

There is no room to guess whether AC-DC adapter for phone idles at 9.3V or else. It is not. This is the beauty of standardization: if the phone says "USB" and has USB connector, it is USB, and the default USB voltage is 5V +-0.5V, period. Therefore as soon as you provide +5V on Type-A receptacle, everything should be safe.

Assuming that you have a standard bike dynamo generator 12V like this one,

[image]

nearly everything is right, except for the brutal miswire of AC-DC rectifier bridge. You need to remove C1 and C2 completely. As shown. it makes no sense whatsoever.

Then, assuming that the J3 (MP1584 step-down module) is wired correctly and set to provide 5-V output, then everything should be just fine, almost. As soon as your spinning wheel will provide more than 8 V DC after rectification on C3, the output +5V should be stable and phone will be happy (the module needs about 3V excess at input over output to operate). The MP1584 also has "undervoltage lock-out" at 3V Vin; below 3V the circuit will shut down. Unfortunately, it is unclear how the MP1584 module will behave if the input voltage is above 3V but below 8 V. So you need to keep an eye on your voltages and experiment a bit at various spinning rates.

Now, if you want your phone to charge a bit faster, connect D+ to D- on USB Type-A receptacle side, and leave them floating. In this way almost any phone will recognize the standard charger signature (called DCP in terms of Battery Charging Specifications v1.2, or preceding "Chinese Federal Standard"), and your phone will take up to 1.5A, likely 900-1000 mA and charge itself faster.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but as already stated in the edits there is no issue with the 9.3V anymore. This was already resolved, and now the voltage is 5V stable. 
I have a Hub-bike dynamo, so not the type from your picture.
C1 and C2 are smoothing capacitors, why would they not make sense there? I was planning on only cutting the path in between them to the AC-part of the rectifier bridge, which is obviously wrong indeed (see my other comment on you and edit of the question).

Comment: Experiments have shown me that the dynamo already has some kind of "undervoltage cut-off". If the wheels spin too slowly, it does not output any voltage. So for now, I'm not really concerned yet about the MP1584 having to do this (ofcourse, when testing on a different bike, this will require testing again).
Good tip on the faster charging by wiring the D+ and D-. I designed my pcb so that this would be possible in the future (after I made sure everything worked as is). However, if I'm not mistaken, a lot of phone manufacturers don't follow this standard?

Comment: @Opifex, C1 and C2 don't make sense because they just effectively increase the value of your main capacitor C3 by just 15%. Get the C3 at 1000uF instead. Regarding phone manufacturers, most phone do support several charging standards, and since the Chinese/CDP signature is the simplest and is implemented in 90% of cheap chargers, they can't afford to miss this one.

Comment: C1 and C2 are Ultra Low ESR capacitors, whereas C3 is a regular elco. 
Would it still make no sense? (I do appreciate the remarks btw. If I could replace 3 capacitors with just 1, I'd be able to make the whole circuit a lot smaller, which is very wanted for this purpose)
What would make a lot of sense ofcourse, is replacing C1 and C2 with just one cap, because the connection in between them has been removed now.